# Is mobile internet actively suppressed in or near supermarkets?

Tags: germany, internet

I’ve lived in Germany for some time, and noticed that in almost all supermarkets (rewe, müller, ikea, etc) i have bad or absent mobile internet. Also, I live near Rewe, and when walking nearby, my mobile internet almost evaporates. When I lived in other countries, such behaviour of mobile internet was rather the exception than the norm. It almost feels like that it is being done on purpose, by actively suppressing the signal strength (or whichever other ways possible). Is it the case?

Comment: It is not actively suppressed. Mobile internet just isn't very good in Germany.

Comment: @Askar Kalykov What would be the objective of doing that? If anyone wanted to suppress mobile signals surely they’d be more likely to do so in zones such as near government buildings, hospitals, airports? A more likely reason might be the building materials used for supermarket construction https://www.wilsonamplifiers.com/blog/11-major-building-materials-that-kill-your-cell-phone-reception/

Comment: I fail to see how this is a travel question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a travel question

Comment: Such stores are typically located in buildings constructed of materials and in ways that are bad for transmission of radio vawes - and no one has a real interest in ensuring good mobile internet there, so it doesn't happen.

Comment: Regarding offtopic - to be honest, i can't find a better SE site for such questions. It's related to travel if you include "living in a foreign country" as part of travel, but of course it depends on the purpose of staying. I had several occasions when i wanted to ask a question because I'm a newcomer in a foreign country, but it seems that there are too few of us to be relevant to SE community... I guess?

Comment: @Askar Kalykov Your question (and others related to living in a foreign country) is better-suited to https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This doesn't really refer to *foreign* countries, and just because it's hard to find a better SE site (and I agree) it doesn't mean it's on topic here.

Comment: You must already know this, and this was not your question, but most supermarkets offer free WiFi for a limited time when you are shopping there.